# How I can get Current photo id in prettyphoto gallery

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I am using prettyphotos to display slideshow and lightbox, but how I can get current photo id which is showing in Lightbox.

PrettyPhotos offer callback function changepicturecallback: function()

I tried it but am not able to get current photo id.

Am using this code

plz help

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme: 'light_square',slideshow:5000,
            changepicturecallback: function(){
            //Run on every image change
                $('.gallery-list li').index($('.selected')).find('img').attr('id');

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
$pp_pic_holder.find("#pp_full_res img").attr("id");
```

prettyphoto is somehow not fetching runtime elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$('.pp_gallery').find('li').index($('.selected'));
```

Comment: Yes. What do you mean by pic id? You could append .find('img').attr('id'); to the above.

Comment: I have assigned pic id attribute to all images anchor tag.

Comment: $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme: 'light_square',slideshow:5000,
    changepicturecallback: function(){
    //Run on every image change
     $('.gallery-list li').index($('.selected')).find('img').attr('src');
     //console.log($(this).parent('a.fbox'));
    }
   });

Comment: Remove the index. You can just use $('.selected img').attr('src'); I think. The current image shown is held inside an li with the class 'selected'. Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to pass image's id to pretty photo is to use link's title attribute.

Like below:

```
<a href="foo/bar/preview.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="<div class='pictureId' style='display:none'>__HIDDEN_IMAGE_ID__</div>picture description">
<img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="filename"/>
</a>
```

And then you can get picture id in changepicturecallback function like this:

```
$("a[href!='#'][rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
   changepicturecallback: function () {
       var id = $(".pp_details .pp_description .pictureId").html();
       alert(id);

        }               
});
```